# how to add the comma in a string to a single cell in csv

Tags: java, csv

while i was trying to write some text to a CSV, I found out that it cut the text at the first comma in the text and thus writing the string to 2 different cell instead of 1. is there anyway around this issue as the text will be crawled from the web instead of input

the gist of the function code is

```
String text = "hello, this is me";
        try {
            PrintWriter csv = new PrintWriter(new File("test.csv"));
            csv.write(text);        
            csv.close();        
        }
        catch(Exception e) {

        }
```

Comment: use opencsv rather than doing it yourself.

Comment: the name of the file is "Comma-separated values", so every comma will be a new value. You can replace it for something else before writing to the file, like csv.write(text.replaceAll(",", "|"))

Comment: you can change the delimiter

Comment: Using a library: opencsv (https://www.baeldung.com/opencsv) or apache commons csv (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) makes it much easier

Comment: thank you for all your suggestions. due to time constraint, I will be using the replacement method but i will definitely look into the opencsv and common csv for future use

Comment: Enclose the string with quotation marks: `if (text.contains(",")) { text = "\"" + text + "\""; }`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**test.csv**

```
a;b;c
d;e;f
```

**test2.csv**

```
a;b;c
,;e;f
```

**Java code using** `opencsv`:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.List;

import com.opencsv.CSVParserBuilder;
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVReaderBuilder;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class Sof {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CSVReader reader;
        try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File("src/main/resources/test2.csv")), ';', Character.MIN_VALUE, '\\', "\n");) {
            reader = new CSVReaderBuilder(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/test.csv"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
                    .withCSVParser(new CSVParserBuilder().withSeparator(';').build()).build();
            final List<String[]> csvBody = reader.readAll();
            System.out.println(csvBody.size());
            csvBody.get(1)[0] = ",";
            writer.writeAll(csvBody);
            writer.flush();
            reader.close();
        } catch (final IOException e1) {
            System.err.println(e1);
        }

    }

}
```